# Mn(OH)2 synthesis

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I have a small problem while reading Inorganic Chemistry Reference book.

The book stated that "In laboratory, Mn(II) hydroxide was prepared by the reaction of Mn(II) salt with alkaline in hydrogen atmosphere"

I guess the hydrogen atmosphere was to avoid Mn(II) being oxidised to Mn(III). Could it be nitrogen gas or other inert gases?

Comment: Possibly yes: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/165867/17368, https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/165889/does-solid-manganese-reacts-with-atmospheric-air-when-heated

Comment: I was also thinking that hydrogen gas could act as reducing agent in this case. Nitrogen, on the other hand, is way more inert to act as reducing agent. I wonder whether this explanation contributing to the usage of H2 atmosphere.

Comment: Look up the Winkler method to measure dissolved O2 in water. In base MnII is oxidized by O2 to MnIII. The O2 could probably be removed by addition of a pinch of bicarbonate to an acidified solution, purging the CO2 with N2 or argon, and degassing the hydroxide.   Alternatively react Mn with HCl maintaining a hydrogen atmosphere and neutralize with degassed hydroxide.

Comment: The described method using hydrogen was published in [Z. anorg. allg. Chem. 1937, 232(4), 369–381](https://doi.org/10.1002/zaac.19372320403) and modified in [J. Am. Chem. Soc. 1950, 72, 2, 856–866](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja01158a056).

Comment: @jimchmst I'm pretty sure it's oxidised to MnO2 - Mn(IV) not III.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nitrogen would work if it were pure. In the real case it may contain traces of air/oxygen, or pick up this impurity as it is being delivered, and Mn(II)  could be sensitive to that. Also the solution may carry air if it has be exposed to said air.

In steel processing applications a mixture of nitrogen with 5% hydrogen is often used, especially for heat treating, with the added hydrogen serving as a "buffer" against air or moisture impurity.